# How to generate a builder class

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have developed in a library a custom javafx.animation.Transition. I want to provide the corresponding builder (like the `TranslateBuilder` for the `Translate` transformation).

As you can see in the [TranslateBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/transform/TranslateBuilder.html) javadoc, the builder class is annotated by `@Generated(value="Generated by javafx.builder.processor.BuilderProcessor")`.

Is it possible to use this processor ?
If yes, how ?

Comment: It's once in OpenJDK but deleted. The source is at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/75b3b8e4530b/javafx-annotation-processor  (I'm going to re-create it as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Builders are created using annotation processor and now, it is internal.

I've created an issue : http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28553

which is for a tracking purpose and for a discussion.